# How to use different colors of Circles using JSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a script that adds a circles on a map, data have been taken from JSON. I want to add a 2 types of circles:

1. First circles are getting property 'jstores' and red color
2. Second circles are getting property 'jcarrera' and blue color.

Only last type in JSON has 'jcarrera' property.

Could you tell me please how to do it in a correct way.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jewellery distribution, presence</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="legend">
Jewellery distribution, boutiques
</div>
<style>
#legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }
</style>
<script>
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: {lat: 7.275, lng: 12.549},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

 // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
 var script = document.createElement('script');

 script.src = 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tPRXQQMM';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);


 map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var jstores = feature.getProperty('jstores');
    var jcarrera = feature.getProperty('jcarrera');
    var ititle = feature.getProperty('ititle');
return {
  icon: getCircle(jstores),
  title: (ititle)
};
});
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}
function getCircle(jstores) {
var circle = {
path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
fillColor: 'red',
fillOpacity: .7,
scale: Math.sqrt(jstores) * 4,
strokeColor: 'white',
strokeWeight: .5
};
return circle;
}
 function getCircle(jcarrera) {
 var circleC = {
 path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
 fillColor: 'blue',
 fillOpacity: .7,
 scale: Math.sqrt(jcarrera) * 4,
    strokeColor: 'white',
 strokeWeight: .5
 };
return circleC;
}
function jewellery_stores(results) {
map.data.addGeoJson(results);
map.data.addListener('click', function(e) {
infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
infowindow.setContent(e.feature.getProperty("text"));
infowindow.open(map);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to a JSON:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tPRXQQMM

Sample JSON:

```
jewellery_stores({ "type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.278842, 25.197623]},"properties": {"jstores": 8,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Dubai Mall</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Damiani:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [54.389373, 24.501259]},"properties": {"jstores": 6,"ititle": "Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>The Galleria at Sowwah Square</b></p>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [47.966734, 29.363636]},"properties": {"jstores": 5,"ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait","text": "<p><b>Salhiya complex</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;2<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>de Grisogono:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.200603, 25.118088]},"properties": {"jstores": 5,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Mall of the Emirates</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [47.935659, 29.302827]},"properties": {"jstores": 4,"ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait","text": "<p><b>al Ostoura</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Damiani:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [54.321782, 24.458713]},"properties": {"jstores": 4,"ititle": "Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Etihad Towers</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>de Grisogono:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [35.50555, 33.898988]},"properties": {"jstores": 3,"ititle": "Beirut, Lebanon","text": "<p><b>Beirut souks</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.443095, 25.260314]},"properties": {"jstores": 3,"ititle": "doha, Qatar","text": "<p><b>Villagio Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.282242, 25.217181]},"properties": {"jstores": 3,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Emirates Towers</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [46.683791, 24.697514]},"properties": {"jstores": 3,"ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Centira Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [50.581376, 26.239843]},"properties": {"jstores": 3,"ititle": "Al-Manamah, Bahrain","text": "<p><b>Moda Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.31919, 25.229147]},"properties": {"jstores": 2,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Wafi Center</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>Mikimoto:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.606182, 25.26973]},"properties": {"jstores": 2,"ititle": "doha, Qatar","text": "<p><b>Qatar Duty Free</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;2<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [39.15077, 21.548994]},"properties": {"jstores": 2,"ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>el Khayyat Center</b></p>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [39.127888, 21.573002]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Am Jad al dar</b></p>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.185453, 25.14133]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>burj al arab</b></p>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.501661, 25.281497]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "doha, Qatar","text": "<p><b>Royal Plaza Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [47.990275, 29.377323]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait","text": "<p><b>Arraya complex</b></p>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [35.874513, 31.967586]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Amman, Jordan","text": "<p><b>Um-Uthaina Vista Building</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [50.222673, 26.305242]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Al Khobar, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>al Jumah city Center</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [39.153526, 21.549449]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Jameel Square</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [46.674271, 24.711465]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Saks Fifth Avenue</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.302142, 25.253076]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Burjuman Center</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.524687, 25.375654]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "doha, Qatar","text": "<p><b>Lagoona mall</b></p>Pasquale Bruni:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [50.180663, 26.291106]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Al Khobar, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Al Rashid Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [39.153759, 21.550658]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>Basateen Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [46.679091, 24.707793]},"properties": {"jstores": 1,"ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia","text": "<p><b>al Akaira Plaza</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>" }},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.116936, 25.130337]},"properties": {"jcarrera": 1,"ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates","text": "<p><b>Atlantis the palm</b></p>CYC:&nbsp;1<br>"}}
]});
```

Thank you in advance.

Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two functions with the same name, change the name of one of them, and use it where appropriate.

```
    map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
        var jstores = feature.getProperty('jstores');
        var jcarrera = feature.getProperty('jcarrera');
        var ititle = feature.getProperty('ititle');
        var retObj = {};
        if (!jcarrera) {
            retObj.icon = getCircle(jstores);
        } else {
            retObj.icon = getBlueCircle(jcarrera);
        }
        retObj.title = ititle;
        retObj.fillColor = 'red';
        return retObj;
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}

function getCircle(jstores) {
    var circle = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        scale: Math.sqrt(jstores) * 4,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: 0.5
    };
    return circle;
}

function getBlueCircle(jcarrera) {
    var circleC = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        scale: Math.sqrt(jcarrera) * 4,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: 0.5
    };
    return circleC;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp95kbj0/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 25.130337,
      lng: 55.116936
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  // script.src = 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tPRXQQMM';
  // document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  jewellery_stores(jsonData);

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var jstores = feature.getProperty('jstores');
    var jcarrera = feature.getProperty('jcarrera');
    var ititle = feature.getProperty('ititle');
    var retObj = {};
    if (!jcarrera) {
      retObj.icon = getCircle(jstores);
    } else {
      retObj.icon = getBlueCircle(jcarrera);
    }
    retObj.title = ititle;
    retObj.fillColor = 'red';
    return retObj;
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}

function getCircle(jstores) {
  var circle = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    scale: Math.sqrt(jstores) * 4,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 0.5
  };
  return circle;
}

function getBlueCircle(jcarrera) {
  var circleC = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    scale: Math.sqrt(jcarrera) * 4,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 0.5
  };
  return circleC;
}

function jewellery_stores(results) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(results);
  map.data.addListener('click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.setContent(e.feature.getProperty("text"));
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var jsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.278842, 25.197623]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 8,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Dubai Mall</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Damiani:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [54.389373, 24.501259]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 6,
        "ititle": "Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>The Galleria at Sowwah Square</b></p>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [47.966734, 29.363636]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 5,
        "ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait",
        "text": "<p><b>Salhiya complex</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;2<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>de Grisogono:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.200603, 25.118088]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 5,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Mall of the Emirates</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [47.935659, 29.302827]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 4,
        "ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait",
        "text": "<p><b>al Ostoura</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Damiani:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [54.321782, 24.458713]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 4,
        "ititle": "Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Etihad Towers</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>de Grisogono:&nbsp;1<br>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [35.50555, 33.898988]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 3,
        "ititle": "Beirut, Lebanon",
        "text": "<p><b>Beirut souks</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [51.443095, 25.260314]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 3,
        "ititle": "doha, Qatar",
        "text": "<p><b>Villagio Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.282242, 25.217181]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 3,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Emirates Towers</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Harry Winston:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [46.683791, 24.697514]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 3,
        "ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Centira Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [50.581376, 26.239843]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 3,
        "ititle": "Al-Manamah, Bahrain",
        "text": "<p><b>Moda Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.31919, 25.229147]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 2,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Wafi Center</b></p>Roberto Coin:&nbsp;1<br>Mikimoto:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [51.606182, 25.26973]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 2,
        "ititle": "doha, Qatar",
        "text": "<p><b>Qatar Duty Free</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;2<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [39.15077, 21.548994]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 2,
        "ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>el Khayyat Center</b></p>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [39.127888, 21.573002]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Am Jad al dar</b></p>Pomellato:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.185453, 25.14133]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>burj al arab</b></p>Graff:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [51.501661, 25.281497]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "doha, Qatar",
        "text": "<p><b>Royal Plaza Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [47.990275, 29.377323]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Kuwait, Kuwait",
        "text": "<p><b>Arraya complex</b></p>Chaumet:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [35.874513, 31.967586]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Amman, Jordan",
        "text": "<p><b>Um-Uthaina Vista Building</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [50.222673, 26.305242]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Al Khobar, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>al Jumah city Center</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [39.153526, 21.549449]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Jameel Square</b></p>Van Cleef:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [46.674271, 24.711465]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Saks Fifth Avenue</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.302142, 25.253076]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Burjuman Center</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [51.524687, 25.375654]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "doha, Qatar",
        "text": "<p><b>Lagoona mall</b></p>Pasquale Bruni:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [50.180663, 26.291106]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Al Khobar, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Al Rashid Mall</b></p>Cartier:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [39.153759, 21.550658]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Jeddah, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>Basateen Mall</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [46.679091, 24.707793]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jstores": 1,
        "ititle": "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
        "text": "<p><b>al Akaira Plaza</b></p>BVLGARI:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.116936, 25.130337]
      },
      "properties": {
        "jcarrera": 1,
        "ititle": "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "text": "<p><b>Atlantis the palm</b></p>CYC:&nbsp;1<br>"
      }
    }

  ]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#legend {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="legend">Jewellery distribution, boutiques</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```